# Native Bootstrap vs Angularjs Bootstrap directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am migrating an existing web application to AngularJS. As the application is already using Bootstrap 3 I am wondering if it is worth re-writing it with [Boostrap Directives](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). My current understanding is that if I use the directives it will be more effective and I'll be able to scrap JQuery. On the other hand, implementing custom widgets should be more straightforward using native Bootstrap + JQuery. I am interested in Pros and Cons of the two approaches.

Comment: if your application can live without JQuery, yes it's worth. http://blog.mikie.iki.fi/2014/04/why-is-angularjs-slower-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Angular-UI's [github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap):

> It is often better to rewrite an existing JavaScript code and create a
>   new, pure AngularJS directive. Most of the time the resulting
>   directive is smaller as compared to the original JavaScript code size
>   and better integrated into the AngularJS ecosystem.

Readability, code size, and Angular compatibility (since most directives allow promises) are enforced comparing to basic plain bootstrap.

That's why I rewrote myself all my bootstrap components using Angular-UI.

Always wonder: "Can I build this thing without importing JQuery?"

Comment: Can you comment on the readability of the HTML source? I imagine that with lots of custom directives and tags a new developer might have a hard time understanding it.

Comment: For instance, it's easier to detect a carousel component with: `<carousel interval="myInterval">` (angular-UI), rather than simple div like this: `<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> `. Imagine your `div` involves more than 6 classes...you would have to detect the `carousel` class... more touchy. Benefit of the directive is that all this boilerplate (the HTML template for carousel) is internal.